# Delay on updating state when changing text field in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
    import React from "react";

    export default class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        items: [],
        text: ""
      };

      handleTextChange = event => {
        this.setState({
          text: event.target.value
        });

      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="appMain">
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
              <input
                placeholder="Enter task: "
                onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                value={this.state.text}
              />
              <button type="submit">Add</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Hey, I'm new to react and can't solve my problem.

Why doesn't my handleTextChange change the state of text straight away? Every time I console.log the state of 'text' it is always one behind what it should be. For example when I enter 'a' into the text field, state.text is "". Then when I enter 'b' and view state.text, it is 'a'. And so on and so forth.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you logging? i cant see any ´console.log´ in your code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.log() after setState() doesn't return the updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state)

Comment: react's `setState` is asynchronous.  You could log the value of state in a callback function that fires after `setState` has finished, like so: `this.setState({ text: textValue}, ()=> console.log(this.state.text));`

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez my thought exactly. I'm assuming OP is doing it in `handleTextChange` function right after the `setState` call. Please keep in mind that `setState` is not an immediate command. You could do the following to console log the state.
`this.setState({text: event.target.value}, () => console.log(this.state))`
UPDATE: @BryanElliott you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks everyone - all these answers were really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate question, but to answer it's because setState is async.

[The docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value) have more information.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful!