# "Print" string letter by letter in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, react-native

I have a React Native component that needs to show an Animation with the letters of a string printing letter by letter. So, logically, I need to update a React state hook inside a loop appending each character of the string to it in a 1 second interval. What I have so far is:

```
let [placeholder, change_placeholder] = React.useState('');
const placeholder_print = () => {
    let temp = "Search for anything"
    console.log("Value of temp is now: " + temp)
    console.log("Length of string: " + temp.length)
    for (let i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
        console.log("Selected character is: " + temp.charAt(i))
        change_placeholder(placeholder.concat(temp.charAt(i)))
        console.log("Placeholder is now: " + placeholder)
    }
}
```

and the React component with the state hook in it:

```
<View>
    <Text>{placeholder}</Text>
</View>
```

Yes, I know that this won't animate. But in the end of the `for`, the value of `placeholder` should logically be the string itself, right? If so, I might be able to get around the animation part with `setTimeout()` inside the for loop to run this every second. But, this is the output when `placeholder_print()` is run:

```
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.166]  LOG      Value of temp is now: Search
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.168]  LOG      Length of string: 6
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.169]  LOG      Selected character is: S
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.170]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.170]  LOG      Selected character is: e
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.170]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.171]  LOG      Selected character is: a
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.171]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.171]  LOG      Selected character is: r
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.172]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.172]  LOG      Selected character is: c
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.172]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.173]  LOG      Selected character is: h
[Fri Jan 15 2021 16:29:30.173]  LOG      Placeholder is now:
```

When running a similar logic in Python or even vanilla JavaScript with no state hooks, this works fine. I don't know if this needs to be implemented with the `<Animated>` component in React Native, or if it's some fundamental difference in the way React state hooks work. I'm stuck here and helping hands will be upvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you aren't seeing the update in your for loop is that `setState()` is asynchronous and the updated state value is not available until the *next* render. So you are just looping through your string, logging the *current* state value (which is an empty string) and then calling `setState` which will be called once the loop is finished. see: [Console.log() after setState() doesn't return the updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state)

When thinking about a loop like this in the context of react you need to take into account the larger state/render cycle. The 'loop' of the animation is actually successive renders triggered by state changes.

The `useEffect` hook gives you a built in method of leveraging this cycle, meaning that you simply need to track `index` through sequential renders (the snippet uses `useRef` to persist the value) and use it to update state, thus triggering a new render, etc.

Here is a quick snippet.

```js
const App = () => {
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = React.useState('');

  const
    string = 'This is the final string.',
    index = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      setPlaceholder(prev => prev + string[index.current]);
      index.current++;
    }
    if (index.current < string.length) {
      let addChar = setInterval(tick, 500);
      return () => clearInterval(addChar);
    }
  }, [placeholder]);

  return (
    <div>
      {placeholder}
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other solution is not working out of the box but was kinda helpful. Here's a more complete working solution.

```
import React from 'react';

interface SlowTextProps {
  speed: number;
  text: string;
}

const SlowText = (props: SlowTextProps) => {
  const { speed, text } = props;
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = React.useState(text[0]);

  const index = React.useRef(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      index.current++;
      setPlaceholder((prev: string) => prev + text[index.current]);
    }
    if (index.current < text.length - 1) {
      let addChar = setInterval(tick, speed);
      return () => clearInterval(addChar);
    }
  }, [placeholder, speed, text]);
  return <span>{placeholder}</span>
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SlowText speed={100} text={"Hello World 1"} />
      <SlowText speed={200} text={"Hello World 2"}/>
      <SlowText speed={500} text={"Hello World 3"} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```