# React nested map sequential render with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, settimeout

My goal is to loop through an array of characters and end on each letter of a given word. My code is currently displaying all of these elements at once, but I want them to display sequentially. Here's what I currently have:

[Current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubEzW.gif)

I'd like to return the array that ends with *h*(wait a few moments), array that ends with *e* (wait a few moments), and so on. I can't figure out to to attach the arrayIndex to the nested map though.

`DisplayName.js`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const DisplayName = ({ characters, first }) => {
  const [charIndex, setCharIndex] = useState(0);
  const [arrayIndex, setArrayIndex] = useState(0);
  
  let arrayContainer = [];

  first.map((letter, i) => {
    arrayContainer.push([]);
    arrayContainer[i].push(characters.concat(first[i]));
    return arrayContainer;
  });

// I can't figure out how to attach arrayIndex here. I am
// also not using j currently, but kept it for now in case I need
// a key for the return statements.
  const fullList = arrayContainer.map((letterArr, j) => {
    return letterArr.map(char => {
        return (char[charIndex])
      })
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let timer;
    let secondTimer;

    if (charIndex < characters.length) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        setCharIndex(charIndex + 1)
      }, 75)
    }

    if (arrayIndex < first.length - 1) {
      secondTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        setArrayIndex(arrayIndex + 1)
      }, 75)
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      clearTimeout(secondTimer);
    };
  }, [charIndex, characters, arrayIndex, first]);

  return (
    <div>{fullList}</div>
  )
};

export default DisplayName;
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import DisplayName from './DisplayName';
import './App.css';

function App() {
    const first = 'hello'.split('');
    const funChars = [
      '⏀', '⎷', '⌮', '⋙', '⊠', '⎳', '⍼',
     '⍣', '╈', '╳', '☀', '★', '☍',  'ↂ','▅'];

  return (
    <div className="glow" style={{ minHeight: '100vh'}}>
      <span style={{ letterSpacing: 12}}><DisplayName first={first} characters={funChars}/></span>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've also tried something like `const [rendered, setRendered] = useState(false);` without success, which I tried attaching to the `j` key.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65735282/13762301

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to iterate over the `first` string up to an index and display a "rolling" fun character while iterating the string.

Intuitively I think it is easier to think of of slicing the front of the `first` string to an index, and appending the fun character.

| iteration | index | text.substring(0, index) | result(s) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | "" | '⏀', '⎷', '⌮',... |
| 1 | 1 | "h" | 'h⏀', 'h⎷', 'h⌮',... |
| 2 | 2 | "he" | 'he⏀', 'he⎷', 'he⌮',... |
| 3 | 3 | "hel" | 'hel⏀', 'hel⎷', 'hel⌮',... |
| 4 | 4 | "hell" | 'hell⏀', 'hell⎷', 'hell⌮',... |
| 5 | 5 | "hello" | 'hello' |

The tricky issue is using two separate timers/intervals to increment the index for the `first` string and to increment an index into the fun characters array. Here is a solution I came up with.

1. Use a React ref to hold a interval timer reference for the rolling fun characters.
2. Single `useEffect` hook to start the "rolling" fun character index incrementing on an interval. Start a timeout on incrementing over the `first` string char array, if there is still length to iterate, enqueue another timeout, otherwise run clean up functions to clear timers and state.
3. Slice the `first` string up to index `arrayIndex` and conditionally append a "rolling" fun character.

Code:

```
const DisplayName = ({ characters, first }) => {
  const charTimerRef = useRef(null);
  const [charIndex, setCharIndex] = useState(null);
  const [arrayIndex, setArrayIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let timerId;
    const cleanupTimerRef = () => {
      setCharIndex(null);
      clearInterval(charTimerRef.current);
      charTimerRef.current = null;
    };

    if (!charTimerRef.current) {
      setCharIndex(0);
      charTimerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
        setCharIndex((i) => i + 1);
      }, 75);
    }

    if (arrayIndex < first.length) {
      timerId = setTimeout(() => {
        setArrayIndex((i) => i + 1);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      cleanupTimerRef();
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      cleanupTimerRef();
    };
  }, [arrayIndex, first]);

  const fullList =
    first.substring(0, arrayIndex) +
    (charIndex ? characters[charIndex % characters.length] : "");

  return <div>{fullList}</div>;
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-nested-map-sequential-render-with-settimeout]

Comment: Drew - Brilliant, this is exactly what I was after. I am still feeling my way around React and this is really helpful. Thanks!