# How can I Use getElementById in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to do auto text animation in my React project. I can make it work in VanillaJS but I don't know how can I do it in React. (I am beginner at React.)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AutoTextSection extends Component {
    writeText = () => {
       let idx = 1

       const text = "This is the text sentence."
       document.getElementById('auto-text').textContent = text.slice(0, idx)

       idx++

       if (idx > document.getElementById('auto-text').length) {
        idx = 1
    }

        setTimeout(this.writeText, 1000)
    }
    render() {
       return (
          <section id="auto-text-sec">
            <h2 className="text-light" id="auto-text">
            {this.writeText()}
            </h2>
          </section>
       )
    }
}
```

Just I can see the first letter. Then it throws me this error :
TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null.

Comment: Use useRef hook to get element.

Comment: use react refs instead of document.getElementById('auto-text') and the error will go away

Comment: Here is an example that uses the React render cycle instead of manipulating the element directly: [“Print” string letter by letter in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65735012/print-string-letter-by-letter-in-react/65735282#65735282)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react, you must use `ref` to be able to access the DOM element directly.

Change your code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AutoTextSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.autoTextRef = React.createRef();
  }

  writeText = () => {
    let idx = 1

    const text = "This is the text sentence."
    this.autoTextRef.current.textContent = text.slice(0, idx)

    idx++

    if (idx > this.autoTextRef.current.length) {
      idx = 1
    }
    setTimeout(this.writeText, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section id="auto-text-sec">
        <h2 className="text-light" ref={this.autoTextRef}>
          {this.writeText()}
        </h2>
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```

In this line, most likely you wanted to use a text node, which is located inside the DOM element:

```
if (idx > this.autoTextRef.current.length) {
```

So use:

```
if (idx > this.autoTextRef.current.textContent.length) {
```

But your code still contains bugs. It is better to start typing in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

Another obvious problem is that when you call `writeText`, you will always have `idx = 1;` Therefore, this state must be endured higher. You can use state for this.

Also in the code there is no condition to terminate the recursive call.

The final minimal working code should look like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class AutoTextSection extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.autoTextRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      idx: 1,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.writeText()
  }

  writeText = () => {

    console.log('writeText')
    const text = "This is the text sentence."
    this.autoTextRef.current.textContent = text.slice(0, this.state.idx)

    this.setState((prev) => ({
      idx: ++prev.idx,
    }))

    if (this.state.idx <= text.length) {
      console.log('writeText recursion')
      setTimeout(this.writeText, 100)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section id="auto-text-sec">
        <h2 className="text-light" ref={this.autoTextRef} />
      </section>
    )
  }
}
```