# Pass params from state to a checkbox tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this code :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.dispatch = props.dispatch;
    this.state = {
        checked: [],
        expanded: [],
    };
    const {dispatch, match, t} = this.props;
    this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
    this.onExpand = this.onExpand.bind(this);
}
onCheck(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked });
    console.log(this.state.checked);
    this.loadProducts(this.state.checked);
}
onExpand(expanded) {
    this.setState({ expanded });
}
render() {
    const { checked, expanded } = this.state;
    console.log(checked);
    ........
    <CheckboxTree
        nodes={this.props.chosenCategory.children}
        checked={checked}
        expanded={expanded}
        onCheck={this.onCheck}
        onExpand={this.onExpand}
        .......
    />
```

The problem is that in `console.log` from `render` function I have the correct `checked` value. But in the function `onCheck` `checked` have the previous value. I don't understand what's the problem. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.log() after setState() doesn't return the updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state) (`console.log()` directly after `setState()` will always show the value during the *current* render. The new state value won't be available until the next render. This is the expected behavior)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of setState, the first one takes an object as a parameter, and the second one takes a function as a parameter. The difference between the two is the first one is asynchronous and the second is synchronous.

So you need to use setState with function as a parameter.

```
onCheck(checked) {
    this.setState((state) => ({ checked}));
    console.log(this.state.checked);
    this.loadProducts(this.state.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the asynchronous behaviour of `setState`, we can't guarantee that the following line will have the updated value, at that particular instance.

In your case, if you want to log the updated value inside `onCheck`, the you can use the callback provided by the `setState` function.

```
onCheck(checked) {
    this.setState({ checked }, () =>  {
        this.loadProducts(this.state.checked); //param - checked will also do
        console.log(this.state.checked);
    });
}
```

now the `console.log` will execute, after successful setState.

Comment: this.loadProducts(this.state.checked) the function here will receive the wrong value due to asynchronous of setState with an object as a parameter, it will receive the previous value of  this.state.checked.

Comment: yes that is true, thanks for letting me know, will update.