# why is my setstate function is not working for the first call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, setstate, use-state

there is a food function with props that is type which is equal to 'Lunch' or 'Dinner'
I need to change the value of LunchStatus when submit is clicked according to the condition on type

```js
const Food = (props) =>{
  const [LunchStatus, LunchUpdate] = useState('Lunch YES');
  const [DinnerStatus, DinnerUpdate] = useState('Dinner YES');
  
  function handlingSubmit(e){
    if(props.type === 'Lunch'){
      LunchUpdate('Lunch NO');
      console.log(LunchStatus);
    }
    else{
      DinnerUpdate('Dinner NO');
      console.log(DinnerStatus);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='food-box'>
      <button  class="button_raise" onClick={handlingSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and output is showing Lunch YES and Dinner YES for first clicks and Lunch NO and Dinner NO for remaining clicks

the output is like when I click both one after one continuously is

```js
Lunch YES
Dinner YES
Lunch NO
Dinner NO
Lunch NO
Dinner NO
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Console.log() after setState() doesn't return the updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons for this behavior:

: `State is updated asynchronously`.
: `In any particular render, state and props don't change, changes are only reflected when the component re-renders.`

```
const Food = (props) => {
  const [LunchStatus, LunchUpdate] = useState('Lunch YES');
  const [DinnerStatus, DinnerUpdate] = useState('Dinner YES');

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(LunchStatus);
  }, [LunchStatus])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(DinnerStatus);
  }, [DinnerStatus])

  function handlingSubmit(e) {
    if (props.type === 'Lunch') {
      LunchUpdate('Lunch NO');
    }
    else {
      DinnerUpdate('Dinner NO');
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className='food-box'>
      <button class="button_raise" onClick={handlingSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: from where did the useEffect come from?

Comment: `import { useEffect }  from 'react';`

Answer (score 0):

Your status was updated.

Just you are not seeing because the state is applied after that.

```
    <div className='food-box'>
      <p>Lanch state: {{LunchStatus}}</>
      <p>Lanch state: {{DinnerStatus}}</>
      <button  class="button_raise" onClick={handlingSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
```

or

```
const Food = (props) =>{
  const [LunchStatus, LunchUpdate] = useState('Lunch YES');
  const [DinnerStatus, DinnerUpdate] = useState('Dinner YES');
  
  function handlingSubmit(e){
    if(props.type === 'Lunch'){
      LunchUpdate('Lunch NO');
      
    }
    else{
      DinnerUpdate('Dinner NO');
     
    }
  }
  console.log(LunchStatus);
  console.log(DinnerStatus);
  return (
    <div className='food-box'>
      <button  class="button_raise" onClick={handlingSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not updating YES at any click, you are only updating NO . Only time it is printing YES is when its initialized with `useState('Dinner YES')`

Comment: but it is printing YES for the first click and not when the page loaded
also for the rest of the clicks it is updating as NO