# Why my function is firing even though it is inside a .then chain (promise/async/await)?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

I am very confused as why my async function does not wait before running the code inside .then

For example, cards should be an array with 102 elements. However, console.log(cards.length) shows 0. Also, the last .then gets excused before any element is put into cards.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // if (!cards.length) {
    //https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=set.id:base1
    async function fetchCards() {
       const response = await fetch('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=set.id:base1', {
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
          'X-Api-key': '22173ccf-376e-4d12-8d50-8b25df6a8e13',
        },
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data.data);
          setCards(data.data);
          console.log(cards.length);
        })
        .then(() => {
           updateDeck(getRandom(cards, 4));
        });
    }
    // }
    fetchCards()
  }, []);
```

Comment: fetchCards's main body does not return anything, so the first `.then()` already gets no data to work with. Instead of `const response = await fetch(...)` just `return fetch(...)`. In fact, why even have fetchCards? Just have `fetch(url, ...).then(response => response.json()).then(......)`, no need to declare-and-invoke, you already have a promise chain by starting with fetch.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I edited the code, but it still length is 0.

Comment: Where is `cards` coming from? Your `then` takes an argument called `data`, not `cards`, so you're not showing all your code, and I'm not going to guess what the rest does. _If_ setCards is a state function, then yes, obviously the associated `cards` won't have updated on the next line: it will be updated at the next render call, and not before. That's how state updates work in React.

Comment: Forgive my utter ignorance. do you mean I should wrap (res.json()) like that to return it?

Comment: cards coming from the useState initialization
  const [cards, setCards] = React.useState([]);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't mix up your `async/await`s with `then` callbacks.
2. Use a new `useEffect` to check for when `cards` changes to call your `updateDeck` function. `setCards` is an asynchronous process so the new state won't be immediately available after you set it. This is why an extra `useEffect` is required for when the state does change.

Here's a shortened example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchCards() {
    const res = await fetch(url, params);
    const data = await res.json();
    setCards(data.data);
  }
  fetchCards();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (cards.length) updateDeck(getRandom(cards, 4));
}, [cards]);
```

Comment: I didn't think about that! I'll try it. However, I edited the code to remove await/async and left only .then. However, still no luck. Any ideas why?

Comment: `setCards` is asynchronous so the new state won't be immediately available after you set it which is why an extra `useEffect` is needed for when the state does change.

Comment: Should I also put whatever function I want to run on cards in the second useEffect?

Comment: @captain: FYI, I've rolled back your edit. Stack Overflow is a bit different from other forums that you may have used, in that the goal is to create question-and-answer pages that are useful to other people; so once an answer has been posted, you shouldn't edit your question to invalidate it. (I mean, if the answer was a result of misunderstanding your question, then it's fine to edit the question to clarify; but if the question is about a bug and the answer shows how to fix it, then you shouldn't edit the question to fix that bug and ask about a new issue.)

Comment: the second useEffect gets called upon first render and throws an error because cards are empty! is there away to make it wait without a conditional?

Comment: @captain Yes. When the `cards` state changes the 2nd `useEffect` is called. It's just a function with a callback.

Comment: It depends on what `getRandom` does, and whether you've set an initial state for `cards`. It's probably just easier to add in a condition to check the cards length. I've updated the answer.