# Incrementing score on React Rap Quiz Not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the setState to increment the score of a quiz I made. I'm using the callback method so I don't mutate the data but it's only showing me a score of 2. I don't get what i'm doing wrong here.. I'm calling the calculateScore function whenever the form is submitted onSubmit={this.calculateScore}.

```
        if(this.state.question1 === '1996') {
            this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score++}
            })
        }

        if(this.state.question2 === 'NWA') {
            this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score++}
            })
        }

        if(this.state.question3 === 'bad-boy') {
            this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score++}
            })
        }

        if(this.state.question4 === 'big-l') {
            this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score++}
            })
        }

        if(this.state.question5 === 'snoop-dogg') {
            this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score++}
            })
        }

        console.log(this.state);
        console.log('calculating')
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `++` that mutates state. Use `return {score: curr.score + 1}`

Comment: I get a score of 0 when I used this way this.setState((curr)=>{
                return {score: curr.score + 1}
            })

Comment: You also shouldn't expect that console statement to work until after the next render. Its receiving stale state.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54713510/691711

Answer (score 1):

You are using the postFix operator `value++` as opposed to prefix `++value`. Try with prefix operator and it should work fine,

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment

Comment: Neither should be used as it mutates state.

Comment: This method is still giving me a score of 2 return {score: ++curr.score}

Comment: I was answering what the potential issue might be. However, I agree with @zero298. Better to not mutate and just do `this.setState((curr)=>({score: curr.score + 1}))`

Comment: And regarding still not working @Brixsta Where is it not working? You have to check in the callback of setState to see the actual value and not immediately as it may not have performed the state updates at that point.