# How to setState inside an onPress Alert function in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, alert

I'm currently playing with ways to change state within an onPress event in React-Native and haven't had much luck. When somebody presses the "Change State?" option in the summoned alert, I would want to change the state to `true` . However, when calling `setState()` or a `useCallback()` which toggles the state, it continues to print **false** printed (twice).

*FYI: I call the alert as `ExampleAlert()` rather than `<ExampleAlert />` elsewhere in my code.*

Does this issue have something to do with the way the Alerts are written in RN, or the fact that Alerts do not trigger a re-render?

```
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const changeStateCallback = useCallback(() => {
    setState(!state);
  }, [state]);

  const ExampleAlert = () => {
    Alert.alert(
      'Title',
      'Message',
      [
        {
          text: 'Change State?',
          onPress: () => {
            changeStateCallback;
            console.log(state);
            setState(true);
            console.log(state);
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'OK',
          onPress: () => {},
        },
      ],
    );
    return null;
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

useState is async, you can not see the change in the same enviroment

so you just need do this:

```
onPress: () => {
            setState(true);
          },
```

or

```
const handlePress =()=>{
 setState(true);
}

    onPress: () => { handlePress },
```

this syntax `() => { }` does not execute yet, it's executed when the user clicked over that.

edit 1:

```
const handlePress =()=>{
 setState(true);
 console.log(state) // here you can not see the change
}

console.log(state) //put your console outside of handlePress to see the change
```

Comment: Did not solve my problem. I used these solution as well as a useCallback() and it continues to print false unfortunately

Comment: @CosmicCat you dont have problem, just you can not see the change in the same enviroment, put your console outside

Comment: Yep I understand that. However, when I do console.log(state) later on it still prints false

Answer (score 0):

I think I know your problem.

`console.log()` is a synchronous function, `setState()` is an async one, called async code won't run until all what's in the current call stack finishes running.

You won't see changes in **state** until later on.

Have you tried visualizing state with debugging tools?

Similar question: [Console.log() after setState() doesn't return the updated state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state)