# How to set a state variable to an empty array in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple useState function that looks like this:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<values[]>([]);
```

Theoretically, this will mean that the state of `value` defaults to an empty array.

I then have a function that I've defined like this:

```
  function handleSelectValue(id: string) {
      let fakeArray:Array<values> = [...Value, DefinedArray.find(x => x.id)]
      setValue(fakeArray);
  }
```

I also tried:

```
  function handleSelectValue(id: string) {
      setValue([...Value, DefinedArray.find(x => x.id)]);
  }
```

I would think that this code should work, however, I get an error that says

> Type 'Value | Undefined' is not assignable to type 'Value'. Type 'Undefined' is not assignable to type 'Value'.

I'm not sure where, exactly, the undefinedness is coming from. It seems to me that my default value of "value" is defined as an empty array of value. (Value is defined elsewhere, to be clear, with a Guid, a name, and a few other descriptor fields).

What is wrong with this code here? I know stateful arrays can be a bit wonky, but this seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: `Array.find` can return `undefined` if no item is found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` if it can't find anything.

`undefined` is not compatible with your typing. So you should only append it here is something to append:

```
function handleSelectValue(id: string) {
      const findResult = DefinedArray.find(x => x.id);
      if (findResult) {
            setValue([...Value, ...findResult ]);
      }
  }
```

Or you could spread an empty array as fallback, if that's more readble:

```js
setValue([ ...Value, ...(DefinedArray.find(x => x.id) || []) ]);
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense -- I was confused because it was returning the error on `...Value` but this has fixed it :)

Comment: Yeah -- you can't accept an answer for 10 minutes after posting, though :)

Comment: One more question: When I do `setValue([findResult])`, it is not setting the `Value` state -- I have run `console.log` before and after running `setValue` and in both cases it is returning an array with length 0. Any idea what might be causing that? or should I make a separate question?

Comment: You'll need to spread it I guess: `setValue([ ...findResult ])`. But keep in mind that [`console.log()` does not show the changed value since `setValue` is async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54713510/console-log-after-setstate-doesnt-return-the-updated-state).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the item exists you can do either of these:

```
function handleSelectValue(id: string) {
  setValue([...Value, DefinedArray.find((x) => x.id)!]);
}
```

or

```
function handleSelectValue(id: string) {
  const item = DefinedArray.find((x) => x.id)
  if (!item) throw new Error('this will never happen')
  setValue([...Value, item]);
}
```